# Laravel orWhere usage

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
$foundItem = ItemDrop::where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id)
        ->where('find_rate','>=',$itemChance)
        ->orderBy('find_rate','desc')
        ->take(1);
```

In my database, I set zone_id = "-1" if I want the `ItemDrop` to be available in **all** zones.

So I've been thinking how I can add it to my query..

```
$foundItem = ItemDrop::where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id)
        ->orWhere('zone_id',"-1")
        ->where('find_rate','>=',$itemChance)
        ->orderBy('find_rate','desc')
        ->take(1);
```

but it doesn't feel right and probably will not work correctly, because I have 2 Wheres and the OrWhere should be included only with the first where: `where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id)`.

How I can get all records of ItemDrop with `zone_id` -1 AND `$this->user->zone_id`?

**How my DESIRED query would look like without Laravel:**

```
SELECT * FROM ItemDrops WHERE( zone_id = "-1" || zone_id = $this->user->zone_id) && find_rate >= $itemChance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$foundItem = ItemDrop::where(function($query){
   $query->where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id)
         ->orWhere('zone_id',"-1");
 })->where('find_rate','>=',$itemChance)
 ->orderBy('find_rate','desc') ->take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function in orWhere to do this. Try something like this:

```
$foundItem = ItemDrop::where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id) 
                     ->orWhere( function ($query) { 
                         $query->where('zone_id',"-1"); 
                     })
                     ->orderBy('find_rate','desc')
                     ->take(1);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I don't get why, but I get `{"error":{"message":"syntax error, unexpected '}'","code":4,"status_code":500}}`

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I didn't check the code. Try again with this edited code.

Comment: Well just tried this, it doens't work correctly - it alwyays finds the item with the "-1" zone_id regardless of the `find_rate`

Comment: Maybe it is due to `take(1)`, try without it.

Comment: Same. If there is any misunderstaing about my question I updated the desired query in SQL that I need to get

Comment: After your edit, I edited the code to put `where('find_rate','>=',$itemChance)` outside the anonymous function

Comment: When `->where('find_rate','>=',$itemChance)` is `false`, like before, I still get the item. It shouldn't /:

Comment: Ok, now I get it... But I would need to test the function. I'll try to write something later.

Comment: No need! Fixed it by changing the first Where to the Where inside the orWHere method. The final result looks like this: `
  $itemChance = mt_rand(1,1000);
  $foundItem = ItemDrop::where('zone_id',$this->user->zone_id)
        ->orWhere( function ($query) {
            $query->where('zone_id',"-1");
        })`