# Laravel orWhere is causing other where queries to be ignored

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have to output data using three different tables, and they have to meet certain conditions.

```
->where('borrows.late_return_status', '=', 1)
->where('borrows.return_date', '=', null)
```

But also, I need to allow the user to search through the list using name or IC.

```
->where('borrowers.borrower_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
->orWhere('borrowers.IC', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
```

My issue is that when the orWhere condition is met, even the necessary conditions are overlooked, and it shows data without late_return_status as 1.

Here's the complete code.

```
$late_books = Borrow::join('books', 'borrows.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
    ->join('borrowers', 'borrows.borrower_id', '=', 'borrowers.id')
    ->where('borrowers.borrower_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->orWhere('borrowers.IC', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->where('borrows.late_return_status', '=', 1)
    ->where('borrows.return_date', '=', null)
    ->get([
        'borrowers.borrower_name', 'borrowers.IC', 'borrowers.phone_no', 
        'books.ISBN', 'books.book_title', 'books.year',
        'books.author', 'books.publisher_name',
        'borrows.issue_date', 'borrows.due_date'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to enclosed the search conditions in a parenthesis.

You can achieve this using Logical grouping (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping).

```
$late_books = Borrow::join('books', 'borrows.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
    ->join('borrowers', 'borrows.borrower_id', '=', 'borrowers.id')
    ->where('borrows.late_return_status', '=', 1)
    ->where('borrows.return_date', '=', null)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
      $query->where('borrowers.borrower_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('borrowers.IC', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    })
    ->get(['borrowers.borrower_name', 'borrowers.IC', 'borrowers.phone_no' ,'books.ISBN', 'books.book_title', 'books.year','books.author', 'books.publisher_name',
           'borrows.issue_date', 'borrows.due_date']);
```

Comment: This question asked and answered multiple times here, example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252919/laravel-orwhere-usage . You should have flag this question as duplicate and should not have earned “free karma”

Comment: I dont care if has been answered many times, it saved my life. Thank you pal.